# Microsoft graph get all users returns only 100 users

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft graph returns **only** `100` users, how could I get all the users from Microsoft graph

```
 var users = graphServiceClient
   .Users
   .Request()
   .GetAsync()
   .GetAwaiter()
   .GetResult();
```

How can I get **all** the users?

Comment: `100` is a default *page size* that's why you have just `100` top records; you can set your own - `.Top(pageSize)`; however `pageSize` can't exeed `999`. Use `NextPageRequest` to obtain *all* pages

Comment: Why are you using .GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of properly awaiting that asynchronous call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MS Graph uses *paged* output with *default page* size of `100` records.
You've read just the first page of the default `100` users.

You, probably, want something like this (queries are usually *slow*, that's why I've made them `async`):

```
var users = await graphServiceClient
  .Users
  .Request()
  .Top(999)  // <- Custom page of 999 records (if you want to set it)
  .GetAsync()
  .ConfigureAwait(false);

while (true) {
  //TODO: relevant code here (process users)

  // If the page is the last one
  if (users.NextPageRequest is null)
    break;

  // Read the next page
  users = await users
    .NextPageRequest
    .GetAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: which version of MS.Graph is this available? I am using 5.32 (latest) and NextPageRequest 
 is not there

Comment: @deathrace: Microsoft Graph has 1.0 version only (and some options are on the beta stage) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/versioning-and-support

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say the MS Graph Client nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/5.11.0?_src=template

Answer (score 5):

Since **Microsoft.Graph** version 5, the `Request()` method and the `NextPageRequest` property do not exist anymore. So, here is my proposed solution based on [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#pageiterator) document.

```cs
static async Task<List<User>> GetUserListAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    UserCollectionResponse? userCollectionResponse = 
        await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();

    List<User> userList = new();

    PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse> pageIterator =
        PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(
            graphServiceClient, userCollectionResponse,
            user => { userList.Add(user); return true; });

    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

    return userList;
}
```

The size of each page can be optionally specified passing the following lambda to the `GetAsync()` method, 999 being the maximum size.

```cs
requestConfiguration => { requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999; }
```

Comment: The answers using .Request() are now obsolete